# Why this piece of code prints `undefined` at the end?

Tags: javascript

While I am running the following piece of code in Chrome's developer tools javascript console,

```
var solution = 1;
for(var i = 1; i <= 12; ++i)
    solution *= i;
console.log(solution.toString());
```

I get the following output:

```
479001600
undefined
```

When I remove the last line, that is `console.log(solution.toString());`, I get just `479001600`. What happens?

Comment: That is because the code you run does not return anything.... there has to be a dupe on this.

Comment: The console records the last returned value of whatever you typed. `console.log` "returns" `undefined` so that's what you see. Without it, the last `solution *= i` is recorded, showing the result you wanted.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol That's exactly the case. Thanks for your help.

Comment: When working directly in the console, there's no need to use `console` to see the variable's value

Comment: Wow..... thought someone would have looked for a dupe instead of an easy answer...

Comment: @epascarello Thanks. How can one disable this action of console, that is disabling the printing of the last returned value?

Comment: Maybe if you change the source code....

Comment: This is "baked-in" to, not only Chrome, but most other developer tool's as well. The feature is not user configurable. Why do you want to do that anyway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `undefined` is simply the console's way of telling you that the statement:

```
console.log(solution.toString());
```

doesn't, itself, return a value (it outputs a value, but doesn't return one). It's not something to worry about when your actual code executes because it's a specific behavior to the developer's console.

As another example, if you type: `5 + 6` into the console, it will report `11` on the next console line, because the console always wants to report any value returned from the statement it just executed.

Answer (score 1):

The console in google chrome will always return the value of the last executed statement.

Since your last statement in the console was

```
console.log()
```

one which did not return any value it showed 'undefined';

Try

```
var a=[];a.push(5);
```

It will show 1 on the next line as the push method returns the length of the  newly formed array